# Parse json object to viewmodel in asp.mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a JSON object:

```
{ "Questions": { "Id": "3a19f538-0cf6-e311-93f5-000c2948090b", "Question": "wedwe", "Answer": "4" }, "items": ["3a19f538-0cf6-e311-93f5-000c2948090b"]},
```

And i'm trying to send it to MVC controler action:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: { "Questions": { "Id": "3a19f538-0cf6-e311-93f5-000c2948090b", "Question": "wedwe", "Answer": "4" }, "items": ["3a19f538-0cf6-e311-93f5-000c2948090b"]},
    dataType: 'json',
    traditional: true,
}).done(AprovingResponse);
```

But in my action:

```
[POST]
public JsonResult AddFeedback(TestModel model)
{
    [...]
}
```

Not whole model is filled:

```
    public class TestModel
    {
        public List<Guid> items { get; set; }
        public List<ViewModelQuestion> Questions { get; set; }
    }

    public class ViewModelQuestion
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Question { get; set; }
        public string Answer { get; set; }
    }
```

Only item list is filled, Questions list contains 0 elements

[image]

I cannot find source of this problem. Can You help me?

**--EDIT--**

When i changed json to mach object collection, there is no diffrence:

```
data: { "Questions": [{ "Id": "3a19f538-0cf6-e311-93f5-000c2948090b", "Question": "wedwe", "Answer": "4" }, { "Id": "3a19f538-0cf6-e311-93f5-000c2948090b", "Question": "wedwe", "Answer": "4" }], "items": ["3a19f538-0cf6-e311-93f5-000c2948090b", "3a19f538-0cf6-e311-93f5-000c2948090b"] },
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your JSON object is not suitable to a class. I think rather should be:

```
{ "Questions": [{ "Id": "3a19f538-0cf6-e311-93f5-000c2948090b", "Question": "wedwe", "Answer": "4" }], "items": ["3a19f538-0cf6-e311-93f5-000c2948090b"]}
```

In your JSON `Questions` property is single JSON object (with fields **Id**, **Question**, **Answer**), but in your view model you are expecting a collection of objects.

Comment: I was trying also this option - no difference

Comment: @Thaven try `data: JSON.stringify({ "Questions": [{ "Id": "3a19f538-0cf6-e311-93f5-000c2948090b", "Question": "wedwe", "Answer": "4" }], "items": ["3a19f538-0cf6-e311-93f5-000c2948090b"]})`. I'm not sure if it will help, but I think it's worth of trying. There could be a problem with content-type in your post. Try to define it in a full way: `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'`.